# Extracting arrays of a symbolic vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a vector of symbolic function of the following form defined in MATLAB R2021a:

```
O_BF(t) =

[JTP*(diff(theta(t), t)*(w1 + w3 - w4 - w2*(cos(beta)*cos(gamma) + 
sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma))) - w2*(cos(gamma)*sin(beta) - 
cos(beta)*sin(alpha)*sin(gamma))*diff(say(t), t)), -JTP*(diff(phi(t), t)*(w1 + w3 - w4 - w2* 
(cos(beta)*cos(gamma) + sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma))) + 
w2*cos(alpha)*sin(gamma)*diff(say(t), t)), JTP*(w2*(cos(gamma)*sin(beta) - 
cos(beta)*sin(alpha)*sin(gamma))*diff(phi(t), t) + w2*cos(alpha)*sin(gamma)*diff(theta(t), 
t))]
```

And I want the following results, which obviously is the extracted parts of the above vector:

```
[JTP*(diff(theta(t), t)*(w1 + w3 - w4 - w2*(cos(beta)*cos(gamma) + 
sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma))) - w2*(cos(gamma)*sin(beta) - 
cos(beta)*sin(alpha)*sin(gamma))*diff(say(t), t))

-JTP*(diff(phi(t), t)*(w1 + w3 - w4 - w2* 
(cos(beta)*cos(gamma) + sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma))) + 
w2*cos(alpha)*sin(gamma)*diff(say(t), t))

JTP*(w2*(cos(gamma)*sin(beta) - 
cos(beta)*sin(alpha)*sin(gamma))*diff(phi(t), t) + 
w2*cos(alpha)*sin(gamma)*diff(theta(t), 
t))]
```

As You can see, this is clearly a vector, but I cannot extract the arrays because MATLAB considers this vector as a function of time. How can I do that?

Comment: I still don't get it. Your desired result is exactly the same as your original, except that it's more readable, now that the separate entries into your array are on separate lines, rather than distributed across several mixed lines. Do you mean that you've got a 1-by-3 symbolic array `O_BF` and want all three parts separately? And that you can't do that, given `O_BF(1)` would index into time, rather than the symbolic array? Can you please add the output of `whos O_BF` as well? Please create a [mcve], i.e. add all relevant definitions of your variables.

Comment: what I do want is access the arrays of the vector. If we use, for instance, O_BF(1), MATLAB will put t=1 into the vector function and will give us a vector which is calculated for t=1. I do not want that. I want all parts of the vector separately. As You know, we can access the arrays of a matrix or a vector with the operator (), but here, it cannot be used. What should I do?

Comment: The behaviour is function-like, rather than array like, so MATLAB evaluates `O_BF(1)`, rather than indexing it as the first element. Again, can you please [edit] the question to add a [mcve] (you could leave out some variables for brevity) and the output of `whos O_BF`?

Comment: A [mre] would be helpful to understand the problem. Do you have a matrix of symbolic expressions, or a symbolic function that returns a matrix?

Comment: I agree that the OP should re-write this as a minimal reproducible example, but at the same time, as someone familiar with Matlab's symbolic math, I think that I understand exactly what is being asked here as it's a common issue with ```symfun```. Based on what I see above (```O_BF(t) = ```...) this is clearly a symbolic function that returns a matrix. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

`O_BF(t)` in your question is a symbolic function with respect to `t` that returns a matrix.

This a common issue when working with symbolic functions and Matlab [`symfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) objects. Here's a simpler example that I think reproduces the behavior observed in the question:

```
syms t a; %define symbolic variables
f(t) = [t a*t 2*t^2]; %define symfun array as function of t
```

Calling `f(1)` evaluates the `symfun` for t = 1 rather than extracting the first element of the 1-by-3 array:

```
>> f(1)
 
ans =
 
[1, a, 2]
```

To access the elements of the underlying array one must assign the contents to an intermediate symbolic variable:

```
g = f(t); %or even f=f(t) to redefine f as sym rather than symfun
g(1)

>> g(1)
 
ans =
 
t
```

This is equivalent to using the [`formula`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.formula.html) function:

```
g = formula(f); 
g(1)

>> g(1)
 
ans =
 
t
```

I know of no current way to directly access the elements of an array defined as a `symfun` without going through the above steps.